# Disable dynamic dropdown option value onchange another dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, dropdown, populate

I have a button when I click "Add new Field" it will populate a new select :[image]

All the dropdown created class is "staff_list" and name="staff_id[]"
The maximum limit for dropdown element created is 5 and user are allow to delete the dropdown created.
[image].

Question: How can I disable dropdown value that have been selected in another dropdown?

- For example if I choose value A in first dropdown,All the created dropdown option with value A is disable.
- If the second drop down selected value is C. All the other option that contain C also is disable
- But if the user delete the dropdown with value A selected.
- option value A change to available in other dropdown.

How can I solve this?

Below is my example code:

```js
var add_button = $(".add_sign");
var wrapper = $(".sign");
var max_fields = 6;
var x = 1;


$(add_button).click(function(e) {
  if (x < max_fields) {
    x++;
    $(wrapper).append('<div  class="input-group sign_user"><select class="staff_list" name="staff_id"><option value="">--Select staff--</option><option value="a">A</option><option value="b">B</option><option value="c">C</option></select><span class="input-group-btn delete_sign"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">X</a></span></div>');

  } else {
    alert('Maximum 5 Authorised Signatory only!');
  }
});
//Delete staff_list
$(wrapper).on("click", ".delete_sign", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  x--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sign">
  <button class="add_sign">Add New Field &nbsp; 
    <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it should be multi-select buttons (checkbox) instead of select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a function that checks every selected value, and then enables all `option`s, searches through the `.staff_list`s for `option`s *in that array that are not currently selected*, and disables them all.

Add that function as a listener to the `wrapper` (with event delegation) *and* run it after more `<select>`s are appended (to ensure the new options' values get properly disabled), *and* run it after `<select>`s are deleted (so that if that `<select>` had anything selected, its value is now enabled again in the other elements).

This ensures a correct re-calculation of disabled `option`s whenever there's a change.

Note that because there are currently only 3 possible values (`a`, `b`, and `c`), only three `select`s can currently be changed - after that, every possible option (except the default) will be disabled.

```js
var add_button = $(".add_sign");
var wrapper = $(".sign");
var max_fields = 6;
var x = 1;


add_button.click(function(e) {
  if (x < max_fields) {
    x++;
    wrapper.append('<div  class="input-group sign_user"><select class="staff_list" name="staff_id"><option value="">--Select staff--</option><option value="a">A</option><option value="b">B</option><option value="c">C</option></select><span class="input-group-btn delete_sign"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">X</a></span></div>');
    recalcDisabled();
  } else {
    alert('Maximum 5 Authorised Signatory only!');
  }
});
//Delete staff_list
$(wrapper).on("click", ".delete_sign", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  recalcDisabled();
  x--;
});
wrapper.on('change', 'select', recalcDisabled);

function recalcDisabled() {
  const selectedValues = $('.staff_list')
    .map((_, sel) => sel.value)
    .get()
    .filter(Boolean); // Filter out the empty string
  $('.staff_list option').prop('disabled', false);
  selectedValues.forEach(value => {
    $(`.staff_list[value!="${value}"] option[value="${value}"]`)
      .prop('disabled', true);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sign">
  <button class="add_sign">Add New Field &nbsp; 
    <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, your explanation make it easier to understand.Thank you so much!!